# Run more sh in terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, sh

How can I run multiple files in one `sh` file?

I tried this but without any luck, seems like it only run the first one. Can someone please help me though?

```
sh ./robots.sh
sh ./update_robots.sh
sh ./update_auctions_end.sh
sh ./auto_bidders.sh
```

Best regards

My files of the .sh files containing while..

`while [ true ]
do
    php /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xxxx/cronjob/auction.end.php
    sleep 30
done`

Comment: It will run them all. It's just waiting for each to complete before executing the next one. Are you trying to run them all simultaneously?

Comment: use `&` at the end for parallel run if you don't have dependencies. is that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get them to run *at the same time* (as mentioned in your comment), use `&`.

In your case:

```
#!/bin/bash
./robots.sh &
./update_robots.sh &
./update_auctions_end.sh &
./auto_bidders.sh &
```

This will run each of the scripts in the background.

Make sure that you've given all the scripts execute permission (easiest way probably `chmod +x script`).

Answer (score 2):

Create single file all.sh

Inside all.sh

```
 ./robots.sh
 ./update_robots.sh
 ./update_auctions_end.sh
 ./auto_bidders.sh
```

ultimately, I am asking to remove sh word in all.sh

Comment: ./system.sh: line 2: ./robots.sh: Permission denied
./system.sh: line 3: ./update_robots.sh: Permission denied
./system.sh: line 4: ./update_auctions_end.sh: Permission denied
./system.sh: line 5: ./auto_bidders.sh: Permission denied
And i have chmoded to 777

Comment: It seems you need to be root user to run sh command for your machine. Try with sudo

Comment: Have you `chmod`ed _each_ file and not just the one with all the other ones in it?

Comment: They don't run at the same time.

Comment: did you add `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` on first line of `all.sh`?